# What do I plug in for $v$ and $\omega$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

> [image: Diagram of cord winding around cylinder]
>
> A uniform solid cylinder of mass $M$ and radius $R$ is free to rotate on frictionless horizontal axle. Two masses m hang from the two cords wrapped around the cylinder. If the system is released from rest then the tension in each cord will be

I want to solve this using the work energy theorem, so I used 
$$2mgh=mv^2+\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$
but what values should I put in for $v$ and $\omega$ in order to get tension?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use $\omega =\frac v R$ to get a relationship of the form $v^2=k h$ where $k$ is a constant related to the given quantities and compare it with the constant acceleration kinematic equation $v^2=u^2+2as$ to get the acceleration $a$ of a mass $m$.
Finally apply Newton’s second law to mass $m$.